# How can I find companies OpenAPI specifications?

Tags: swagger, openapi

How can I find companies and organizations' OpenAPI specifications (the JSON or Yaml file)?

Or is it simply up to each company to decide whether they want to share it with the public? (e.g. stripe: https://github.com/stripe/openapi)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems apis.guru have a functionality to browse public OpenAPI specifications: https://apis.guru/browse-apis/

Answer (score 2):

It's up to the company. If they want users to find their specification, they will probably reference it on their API Documentation.

See for example here: https://petstore.swagger.io/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no known official list of publicly available OpenAPI specifications?

Comment: Not to my knowledge

Comment: This site expose public OpenAPI specifications: https://apis.guru/browse-apis/ :)